# 301 redirect on pagination with parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to setup a 301 redirect with parameters such as:

- `http://www.domain.com/?p=2` should redirect to `http://www.domain.com/page/2/`
- `http://www.domain.com/tag/tagname/?p=2` should redirect to `http://www.domain.com/tag/tagname/page/2/`

Obviously the redirect should work with all the page numbers (1,2,3,4,etc) and with all the tag names.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: What did you try so far? There are a hundred questions like this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: unfortunately didn't find any which works so far